# Remove UtcOffset from DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I need the value of DateTime.Now in round trip format without the utcOffset. Based on the this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) if you create a new instance of DateTime without the UtcOffset it produces the format I want.

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 4, 10, 6, 30, 0);
// Displays 2008-04-10T06:30:00.0000000
```

but if I use DateTime.Now, i get the offset in the string:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("o")
// Displays 2012-02-08T14:11:12.8378703-05:00
```

I could just use substring or populate a DateTime instance without it, but I  was wondering if there is a way to remove the UtcOffset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The UTC offset (e.g., "-05:00" or "Z") is omitted if the [DateTime.Kind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx) is neither [Utc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx) nor [Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx).

You can create such a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) value as follows:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
// "2012-02-08T19:19:38.5767158Z"

new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks).ToString("o");
// "2012-02-08T19:19:38.5767158"

new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks).ToString("o");
// "2012-02-08T14:19:38.5767158"
```

Comment: Looks like I beat you by about 76 seconds... ;-)

Comment: I'll go with this one, because I didn't want to strip the Z, so the Ticks example is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want, you can use [DateTime.UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx).

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("o")
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")
```

Outputs:

```
2012-02-08T13:18:22.4459488-06:00
2012-02-08T19:18:22.4599488Z
```

Answer (score 1):

I just zeroed mine out by using

```
new DateTimeOffset(Date_Goes_Here, TimeSpan.Zero);
```